# meaning of the phrase "beyond breaking"?

Tags: meaning

It is from [Crash Course Astronomy.](https://youtu.be/jDF-N3A60DE) That phrase was used at around 11:00 minute. Here it goes:

> It will be as if that part of the Universe across the horizon is ripped away from us, beyond breaking.

I googled the phrase, but what I have found was the phrase *breaking point*. I feel these two phrases are related, but still I cannot quite get what it means in the sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real wording is:

> It will be as if that part of the Universe across the horizon is ripped away from us, **stretched beyond breaking**.

That part of the Universe will be stretched until it reaches a breaking point, and then stretched some more, so that the actual breaking occurs. Hence, "beyond breaking".

> [image]

Comment: +1 for the answer and +1 for noticing that OP had dropped the word **stretched**.